# Behat selenium Chromedriver CreatePlatformSocket error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I am trying to run test with selenium and chromedriver.
i have a centos 6.7 installed chrome and used chrome lib from chromedriver  ( found script here https://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/)

```
    front:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://urlfront/'
      browser_name: chrome
      sessions:
        default:
          selenium2:
            wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'
            capabilities:
                browser: chrome
  suites:
   front:
    filters:
      tags: front
admin:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://url/'
      browser_name: chrome
      sessions:
        default:
          selenium2:
            wd_host: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
            capabilities:
                browser: chrome
  suites:
   admin:
    filters:
      tags: admin
```

this is my behat .yml 
im starting selenium with this command :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

when I run behat, i got an error on selenium

```
[27,690][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error, errno=97: Famille d'adresses non supportée par le protocole ( address family not supported)
```

this error loop for a while and at the end it show me this

```
12:01:01.718 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I don't know where to search, is that an error from chrome not starting or  protocol not supported or both ? 
hope someone can help me on this I tried a lot of things reinstalled chrome with the script but maybe it was not cleaned and I still have a wrong version ?